# Define a verb Centigrade in J programming

Tags: j

When defining the verb **centigrade** to convert its argument from a Fahrenheit to a centigrade, the code in the book 'J Primer' is:

```
   centigrade =. 3 : 0
t1 =. y. - 32
t2 =. t1 * 5
t3 =. t2 % 9
)
```

However, I had the spelling error in 'y.' part.
But when I type 'y' instead of 'y.' in the definition, it works.

```
   centigrade =. 3 : 0
t1 =. y - 32
t2 =. t1 * 5
t3 =. t2 % 9
)
```

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, the J language used `x.` and `y.` for the internal arguments to an explicit verb. You can reset to allow for `y.` or `x.` if you want to use legacy code by using the foreign conjunction `9!:49`

`9!:49 [ 0` for not accepting `y.` `9!:49 [ 1` for accepting `y.` `9!:48 ''` gives the current status of the flag. http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx009.htm (bottom of page)

```
   test=: 3 : 'x. + y.'
|spelling error
|   x. + y.
|   ^
|   test=:3     :'x. + y.'
   9!:49 [ 1

   test=: 3 : 'x. + y.'
   9!:49 [ 0

   test=: 3 : 'x. + y.'
|spelling error
|   x. + y.
|   ^
|   test=:3     :'x. + y.'
```